# Meaning of the verb "to intergonize"

Tags: verbs

I have come across the verb "to intergonize" while watching Homeland Season 1. There was a phrase "She wasn't worth intergonizing them". Dictionaries don't have this word, and neither does Google.

I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance,
Ekaterina

Comment: Are you sure that it wasn't "antagonize" or "interrogate"? Can you point us to a specific time/episode? Maybe you simply misheard.

Comment: (1) The phrase sounds ungrammatical. (2) Are you sure you heard the word right?

Comment: No, I am not sure I heard it right. This was in Season 1 Episode 3 time 41.40

Comment: No results for intergonize on Google Books, but one for [intergonise](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=intergonise)

Comment: @JackGraveney Thank you very much for your help! The word turned out to be "antagonising"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's a on-off mishearing.

Comment: But it's not a bad [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau)!

Comment: @JackGraveney - That looks like an OCR error.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, seems to read "intercourse" now I look over it again. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

I just watched it again. This is the exact transcription of the part you are mentioning.

> They're at the airport by now, heading back to the Gulf.
>
> You let them leave? If it makes a difference, State Department made
>   the call.
>
> Said it wasn't worth ***antagonizing*** the Saudis.
>
> Yeah, you mean she wasn't worth ***antagonizing*** them.
>
> It hurts to lose an asset, Carrie.
>
> I get that.
>
> But she's gone.

Comment: @Ekaterina You are welcome. I should have posted it as a comment, but it was too long. :-)

Comment: @Ekaterina - Sorry that you feel so antagonized by this.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is an informal word for "antagonize." It is pronounced /anˈtaɡəˌnīz/, and means to cause someone to feel anger.

Comment: This is certainly sometimes pronounced in the way OP thinks she heard.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by OP

Comment: OP means Original Post. This would refer to your question, in this case.

Comment: @Ekaterina: Stack Exchange has its own jargon (I encourage you to take the tour and find out more about us). OP stands for 'Original Poster': in this case, yourself.

Comment: @TimLymington Thank you for the answer! I will take the tour around here. Thanks again!